# Force.com pulg-in for eclipse facing Error "No repository found at http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42."

Tags: force.com-ide

installing force.com IDE pulg-in via Eclipse Marketplace[image: See in image----]

Kindly Help me out..

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Force.com IDE was deprecated. It isn't available anymore

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm

VS Code with Salesforce Extension Pack is the free official salesforce replacement.

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode

If you hate VS Code and have some cash:

- Iluminated Cloud http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/
- Welkin Suite
  https://welkinsuite.com/

Are a couple of paid third party options (I'm not affiliated with either)

Comment: +1. Beyond deprecated, it is end-of-lifed and no longer available: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed  Is there any way to connect salesforce pulg-in with eclispe?

Comment: No. That product is dead. You'll need to use a different IDE, such as Visual Studio Code or Illuminated Cloud.